# Size of a natural transformation and the Yoneda Lemma

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, yoneda-lemma

Appearing on the second page (under the section Digression: Size worries) of the following paper about the Yoneda Lemma:

http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/categories/yoneda.ps

It says that $a$ $priori$ $[\mathcal C^{op},Set](H_A,X))$ is a class. I don't understand why this is the case.

My understanding is that $a$ $priori$ each member of $[\mathcal C^{op},Set](H_A,X))$ is a class.

So it seems to me that $[\mathcal C^{op},Set](H_A,X))$ could be a collection of proper classes.

I've looked at this [How does the Yoneda lemma imply that $\mathrm{Hom}(yC,P)$ is a set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354824/how-does-the-yoneda-lemma-imply-that-mathrmhomyc-p-is-a-set), but it hasn't helped me much.

Any help is appreciated
-Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So it seems to me that $[\mathcal C^{op},Set](HA,X)$ could be a collection of proper classes.

You're right. Each natural transformation $\alpha\colon H_A\to X$ is a class and proper when $Ob(\mathcal C)$ is proper. Therefore $[\mathcal C^{op},X](H_A,X)$ is apriori a conglomerate, see p 15-16 in [Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf), which is just a extension of the class concept, much as in the same way class was an extension of set. Yoneda's lemma shows that this conglomerate is a small conglomerate and for all practical purposes can be considered a set.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. Let me see if I have this straight then (using the notation of the PDF): 

If $[\mathcal C^{op},Set](H_A,X)$ is a class, then the Yoneda Lemma shows that $[\mathcal C^{op},Set](H_A,X)$ is an object in $Sets$ and finds a bijection (ie isomorphism) between $[\mathcal C^{op},Set](H_A,X)$ and $X(A)$ in $Sets$. 

Otherwise, the Yoneda Lemma shows there is a "bijection" (ie one-to-one correspondence) between $[\mathcal C^{op},Set](H_A,X)$ and $X(A)$, which is not necessarily a bijection (ie isomorphism) in $Set$.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I wouldn't say $[\mathcal C^{op}, Set](H_A,X)$ is an OBJECT in $Set$, but rather it is essentially a set, which means there is a bijection between its members (which are classes) and the members (set elements) in an object in $Set$, namely $X(A)$.

Comment: It is similar to saying that the conglomerate (Dr. Leinster uses class here) $\{Group\}$ which consists of one class, the class of all groups, is essentially a set since there is a bijection $1\to \{Group\}$. You can't say $\{Group\}$ is a set, since its members are not sets. But if you are just collectivizing one thing, it is reasonable to call it essentially a set with one member.

Comment: By "class" I mean the set-theoretic notion of a class, and my understanding is: when $[\mathcal C^{op},Set](H_A,X)$ is a class, then the existence of a bijection between the set $X(A)$ and the conglomerate $[\mathcal C^{op},Set](H_A,X)$ implies that $[\mathcal C^{op},Set](H_A,X)$ is a set and therefore an object in $Set$.

Comment: Also, in the case that $[\mathcal C^{op},Set](H_A,X)$ is not a set, then why do we use the isomorphism symbol to say there is a bijection, in the Yoneda Lemma? Isomorphism seems to imply that there is a bijection in $Set$. But as we've discussed, the bijection need not be in $Set$.-Thanks

Comment: Recall that a "proper class" (in the von-Neumann-Godel-Bernays sense) is a class which is not contained in any other class. So, if a natural transformation $\alpha$ is a proper class (this happens when $Ob(C)$ is a proper class) and $\alpha \in [C^{op},Set](H_A,X)$, then it is a member of something larger than "class" since classes are not members of classes. Therefore, $[C^{op},Set](H_A,X)$ must be larger than a class, i.e., a conglomerate. Don't let the terminology in Leisters paper confuse you. Usually class="large" set, where we have fixed some notion of set beforehand.

Comment: These are good questions. I am probably not the best suited to answer all of them. But my guess is that since the bijection cannot occur in the category $Set$ (since $[\mathcal C^{op},Set](H_A,X)$ is not an object in $Set$) but in the larger full subcategory of $Ens$ consisting of conglomerate sets (see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46060/the-categories-set-and-ens).